# Apache Rewrite condition assistance

Tags: apache

I've got an httpd-vhosts rewrite rule configured to forward any port 80 traffic to an port 443 URL:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond   %{SERVER_PORT}  !^443$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/dir/subdir$1 [L,R]
```

This works fine when end-users navigate to port 80 first. However end-users that navigate to port 443 don't process the rewrite rule since it's not in the httpd-ssl configuration file.

What's the proper way to include an httpd-ssl rewrite condition so that if the URL isn't already rewritten I can rewrite it?

I've tried various options, the last httpd-ssl rewrite attempt as follows:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT} !^/dir/subdir$
RewriteRule ^/(.*) /dir/subdir$1
```

Comment: What is your ultimate goal? Looks like you are trying to write all requests into `dir/subdir`.  Please provide an example URL your end user would see, and what it should be rewritten/redirected to, both for SSL & non-SSL.

Comment: The ultimate goal is for any end-user going to www.example.com or example.com regardless of HTTP or HTTPS will be redirected to       https://www.example.com/dir/subdir on port 443

Answer (score 0):

The need to redirect into SSL will require you to have two rewrite rules, and therefore possibly two redirects  for visitors. You can't easily both force SSL and perform your redirection in one rule.

It's recommended to use `%{HTTPS}` instead of checking the port, because it allows you to use alternate ports like 80 or 8443 if it ever becomes necessary.

```
RewriteEngine On

# First force SSL:
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]

# Then redirect all requests not already in dir/subdir into that path
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/dir/subdir
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/dir/subdir/$1 [L,R=301]
```

If you need to force all users onto `www.example.com`, replace `%{HTTP_HOST}` with `www.example.com` in both of the `RewriteRule` above. Using `%{HTTP_HOST}` will permit the domain to stay on whatever the user requested, e.g. `example.com` instead of `www.example.com`.

Comment: Hi Michael,  thank you very much for your input.  Prior to reading your latest reply I had managed to accomplish my goal.  I've implemented your suggestion of used in the %{HTTPS} parameter over the !^443 using in the original.  I had the force ssl configuration in the httpd-vhosts.conf file.  Within the httpd-ssl.conf I used a RedirectMatch ^/$ https://www.example.com/dir/subdir/$1 which appears to have done the trick.  Is the method I've implemented inferior to what you've suggested above?

Comment: @Pete.Jibe Not inferior, just different. Most people coming here to Stack Overflow with Apache questions don't have access to apache .conf files so I'll tend to reply with htaccess-ready solutions.  Myself, I tend to find RedirectMatch a little less explicit to read than RewriteRule, especially if it has to be mixed with other rewrite rules, but either approach is valid.  RewriteRule can be a lot more flexible if you have to change things later or add exceptions, however.